# What will happen if i left unwanted whitespaces in python code? Will it increase memory? Will it reduce efficiency?

Tags: python

Example:

```
a = 10
b = 5
```

At declaration of variable `a` I left extra whitespace by overruling pep8 condition.
Will whitespaces will consume memory, when we go for big codes?

Comment: Whitespace will not be a bottleneck in your code; sounds like premature optimization

Comment: There comes a point when you need to consider readability and maintenance over performance... I think you've reached that point

Answer (score 4):

The only unmeasurably small possible slowdown is in the initial parsing phase, just because the interpreter has to read slightly more data from disk and ignore it, but that's going to be completely irrelevant from a performance standpoint (unless you start adding megabytes of spaces ;-) ); anyhow, after your code gets in AST form (and then bytecode form) whitespace disappears completely.

The `.pyc` files generated from a file with or without trailing whitespace are going to be identical (modulo debugging information), so the actual execution speed of the code can't suffer even slightly.

Answer (score 0):

As per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) White spaces should used as per need of Styling.

There is no such effect on execution speed, however, it makes code better for reading, optimizing and understanding as well. You can read more [here.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves)